# How to use php arrow function in Laravel web.php Route

Tags: php, laravel, arrow-functions

hi I want to use this in laravel

```
Route::get('/a',fn() => view('a'));
```

instead of :

```
Route::get('/a', function () {
    return view('a');
});
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Which version of pop are you using? Arrow functions are PHP 7.4 thing

Comment: "but it doesn't work" try to be more specific. The people here don't know either and we cannot tell since it is your environment and your code. Try to make it clear for others so that they can help you faster and more efficiently. If something does not work then most of the time you get an error. Or you can debug the values and do before/after or is/should comparisons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried `Route::get('/a',fn() => view('welcome'));` and worked fine.

Did you check that the view 'a' exists?

Give more detail of the error. Maybe is something else that is not working.

Comment: thanks i have a view 'a' maybe it's the php version  i have ~ PHP 7.3.12-1 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2019 07:34:08) and  the syntax error is {
 "message": "syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')'",
}

Comment: Well as mentioned above, you need PHP 7.4 (that's when arrow functions got added to the language), so that explains it.

Comment: That must be your problem since arrow functions was includad at PHP 7.4